# Can I save an Azure VM Custom image locally?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I was following this tutorial to create a custom VM:

http://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/08/step-step-guide-create-azure-custom-image/

The idea is that I would start with a base image from the marketplace and then tweak it for my needs. After that I would save the image so I can reuse it another time.

I'm interested in being able to create a custom VM image and then being able to share this amongst my colleagues, so that they can spin up a particular VM with the same customisation for their own azure accounts.

Is it possible to save this image locally, or similar so that it can be distributed, say from a shared network drive?

I'm pretty new to this, so even if this is way off, perhaps someone could point me in the general direction?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to save that image to a storage account in Azure and provide users with the storage account name and key to access. That way they can copy it to their subscription. Also, have you check the new feature we have Shared VM Imae Gallery? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I know there is no way to download the Azure image directly. But there are a lot of means to get the same result.

The image is also a VHD file and it can be from the os disk or the snapshot of the VM. So you can download the os disk or the snapshot of the VM and then share it. When you share them it also means you share the image. Also, you could try the way that [Shared VM Imae Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries) as the comment describe.

Comment: downloading the snapshot of the VM sounds like the kind of thing I'd like to do. i really just want to offer a colleague a fast way of spinning up a VM exactly like mine

Comment: @dstewart101 You can try it, if it works or need more help please let me know.

Comment: i'll be trying this tonight again. thanks for your help. i've been following the instructions in this link now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd i'm in the process of downloading a 127gb image of a disk now. seems i should have pitched for something smaller and then tried to increase the disk size once i have the image in hyper-v or similar.

Comment: @dstewart101 OK, please let me know if there is a result or for more help.

Comment: @dstewart101 Do you finish the try? And what is the result?

Comment: @dstewart101 Does the answer work to you? If it works you can accept it, thx.